# What causes Page Redirect when adding / to URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a url redirect to the detail.php page from my own site. If I put "/" at the end of this redirect, that is, the url, it redirects me to index.php. What should I do so that it does not redirect to Index.php?

htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^([^/_.]+)$ detay.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^sayfa/([^/_.]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]


#404 hata sayfası yönlendirme kodu
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST On
</IfModule>
```

I've tried and tested regex definitions, htaccess types and how to put "/" at the end of the url through Google, with many results and I've tried but failed.

Comment: Look at your conditions ... you certainly do not have a file called `/some/path/file/.php`, do you? So that condition won't get true whenever you have a trailing slash. You could add a rule prior to that which strips any trailing slash from requested URLs, but that would hae to trigger an external redirection.

Comment: FYI: Your first RewriteCond & -rule are pretty pointless - the condition will never match, `localhost/` is not a host name.